# Basic LINQ for updating a collection property on object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am wondering how I would do this basic operation using LINQ. I have an update function that takes a view model object which has a property that is a list of another view model object, and I would like to loop through those and update the db. Here is the code I have:

```
public void UpdateInspection (EditInspectonViewModel editedInspection)
    {
        //get the inspection we're editing
        Inspection inspection = _repo.GetAll<Inspection>().Single(x=>x.Id==editedInspection.Id;

        //set the values to what was passed in
        inspection.Name = editedInspection.Name;
        inspection.Description = editedInspection.Description;

        // Here is where I'm stuck (note-Damages is of type  DamageViewModel)
        foreach (var damage in editedInspection.Damages)
         {
        // How do I get a reference to the inspection record's corresponding
        // damages records?
         }

        _repo.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Is there a LINQ syntax that will allow me to update the values in these child records (ie., inspection damages)?

Comment: [C# Linq Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/)

Comment: How do I get a reference to the inspection record's corresponding
damages records to update them to what was passed to my function?

Comment: Shouldn't you `for` loop be using `inspection.Damages` and not `editedInspection.Damages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, you can use Join LINQ method, like that:

```
public void UpdateInspection (EditInspectonViewModel editedInspection)
{
    //get the inspection we're editing
    Inspection inspection = _repo.GetAll<Inspection>().Single(x=>x.Id==editedInspection.Id;

    //set the values to what was passed in
    inspection.Name = editedInspection.Name;
    inspection.Description = editedInspection.Description;

    // Here is where I'm stuck (note-Damages is of type  DamageViewModel)
    var damages = editedInspection.Damages
                                  .Join(inspection.Damages, 
                                        d => d.Id, d => d.Id, 
                                        (vmDmg, dbDmg) => new { vmDmg, dbDmg });
    foreach (var damage in damages)
    {
        damage.dbDmg.Property = damage.vmDmg.Property;
    }

    _repo.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I will try this tomorrow to see if effective for my solution. 

Is this a normal way to handle something like this? I can't make much sense of LINQ queries yet (just started). I know SQL, but this to me is not very clear or readable (linq/lambdas in general). Just wondering if there is a different/better way to do something basic using linq like this that is more readable. 

Thanks in advance for your valuable input

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thank you. Are there other linq operators for this parent-child record scenario?

Comment: @inspectorGadget could you set my answer as the correct one?! There are many linq methods, you can see them here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried, but I need to have "a total of 15 reputation" to mark your answer as useful, according to this site. Hopefully someone reading this will mark it on my behalf.

Brand new here...

Comment: @inspectorGadget No, you dont need to mark as useful, you need to click in "check" simbol, 

**Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)**